# Convert DateInterval object to seconds in php

Tags: php, date, time, seconds

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

How do i convert the above `$interval` to seconds in php

Comment: Note that neither minute nor hour is a precise unit of time. A minute may span 59, 60, or 61 seconds, an hour may contain 3599, 3600, or 3601 seconds. And converting months to seconds is complete nonsense.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a function `format` for this. But it wont return the number of seconds. To get number of seconds you use this technique

```
$seconds = abs($datetime1->getTimestamp()-$datetime2->getTimestamp());
```

If you really want to use `$interval` you need to calculate it.

```
$seconds = $interval->days*86400 + $interval->h*3600 
           + $interval->i*60 + $interval->s;
```

Here

- `86400` is the number of seconds in a day
- `3600` is the number of seconds in an hour
- `60` is the number of seconds in a minute

Comment: it is returning `0 seconds`

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, thats why I changed my answer

Comment: This is still error prone. `$interval->days` _may_ be a boolean. This would be safer by using `$interval->y`, `$interval->m`, and `$interval->d` instead of `$interval->days`. The immediate problem you'll face is deciding how many days to use in a month. @Brilliand's answer fixes this, but has its own limitations as well. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 49):

Another way to get the number of seconds in an interval is to add it to the zero date, and get the timestamp of that date:

```
$seconds = date_create('@0')->add($interval)->getTimestamp();
```

This method will handle intervals created via the DateInterval contructor more or less correctly, whereas [shiplu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277647/638544) will ignore years, months and days for such intervals.  However, shiplu's answer is more accurate for intervals that were created by subtracting two dates.  For intervals consisting only of hours, minutes and seconds, both methods will get the correct answer.

Comment: @Brilliand Why is this solution less accurate for intervals that were created by subtracting two dates? I don't understand how. Can you explain ?

Comment: @MaxiWheat Say the time interval was created by subtracting 2015-02-01 from 2015-03-01.  That's a difference of one month, which happens to equal 28 days.  Shiplu's method will treat this as a 28-day interval, whereas my method will treat it as a one-month interval, arbitrarily pick January as the month, and produce a timestamp based on the 31 days in January.

Answer (score 1):

I would only add to [shiplu's answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14277647/5361495)

```
function dateIntervalToSeconds($interval)
{
    $seconds = $interval->days*86400 + $interval->h*3600 
       + $interval->i*60 + $interval->s;
    return $interval->invert == 1 ? $seconds*(-1) : $seconds;
}
```

To handle negative intervals.

Note that - contrary to [Brilliand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22465402/5361495) - The code above will consider correctly years, months and dates. Because $interval->days is an absolute value ($interval->d is relative to the month).

**EDIT:** this function is **still not correct**, as pointed out by @Brilliand. A counter-example is

```
new DateInterval('P4M3DT2H');
```

It doesn't handle months well.

Comment: An example of an interval this will fail on is `new DateInterval('P4M3DT2H')`.  Try it and see - the `days` variable is empty, despite the interval spanning roughly 123 days.

Comment: In the future, if you're going to accuse me of being wrong, I request that you do so in a comment on my answer.  It took me a long time to notice this.

Comment: @Brilliand, you are right. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It isn't just months.  Try `new DateInterval('P3D')` - the `days` variable is *still* empty.  A DateInterval created with `new` just never fills in that variable.  That's what I meant by "the DateInterval contructor".