# dividing one DateInterval by another

Tags: php, datetime

Suppose I have one DateInterval that is 1 year, and another that is 3 months.

Is it possible to divide one by the other and get an answer of 4, that is, there are 4 intervals of 3 months in an interval of 1 year?

Comment: Question: what would you expect `1 month divided by 7 days` to return?

Comment: There might be a way to get this done. Can you post 2 or 3 examples of what you want to achieve? Example: var $datainterval = 4; $month = 3 outcome = 4.

Comment: @CarlosR I think you mean "achieve" not "archive". ;D

Answer (score 0):

Dates do not lend themselves easily to mathematical operations. We can just about do addition and subtraction, that's about it. Multiplication makes little sense (1 month times 12 months = 1 square-year?) but division can be understood as "how many of this interval are there?" which can be implemented by repeated subtraction.

Create a `DateTimeImmutable` for `now`. `add` the first of the intervals you are trying to perform division on. Then, `subtract` the second interval until you obtain a new date/time that is less than (or equal to) your original `DateTimeImmutable`. Count how many times this takes. That's your division answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try converting your `DateInterval`s to seconds and dividing that:

```
$dateInterval1     = new DateInterval('P1Y');
$dateInterval2     = new DateInterval('P3M');
$dateInterval1Secs = date_create('@0')->add($dateInterval1)->getTimestamp();
$dateInterval2Secs = date_create('@0')->add($dateInterval2)->getTimestamp();

var_dump($dateInterval1Secs / $dateInterval2Secs);
```

Of course, this is really precise, and this code outputs `4.0555555555556`

Converting to seconds from [Convert DateInterval object to seconds in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277611/convert-dateinterval-object-to-seconds-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Directly no, since `DateInterval` is an object. Something like this could help based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277611/convert-dateinterval-object-to-seconds-in-php) answer

```
$y = new DateTime('@0');
$x = new DateTime('@0');
$secondsOfYear = $y->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'))->getTimestamp();
$secondsOfThreeMonths = $x->add(new DateInterval('P3M'))->getTimestamp();

print_r([$secondsOfYear,$secondsOfThreeMonths,(int)($secondsOfYear/$secondsOfThreeMonths)]);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => 31536000
    [1] => 7776000
    [2] => 4
)
```

Check it out on [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99a415ef3f29d4a24830f518c5db54721477950e)